# Why does posix_spawn() fail where popen() works?

Tags: c, linux, popen, spawn

I'm successfully using `popen()` to run commands from within my C program. As I understand, it uses `fork()` and `exec()` (or variants of those) behind the curtains. This works very well:

```
FILE *fd = popen("xterm", "r");
pclose(fd);
```

... will bring up a new xterm window, as expected.

Now I'm trying to achieve the same with `posix_spawn()`, which I understand to be possibly more resource-friendly, especially if we don't plan on communicating with the new child process:

```
/* p.we_wordv contains the argv, index 0 holds the actual command */
pid_t pid;
posix_spawnp(&pid, p.we_wordv[0], NULL, NULL, p.we_wordv, NULL);
```

... but this, for `xterm` as the command, yields the following on the parent's output:

```
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display:
xterm: DISPLAY is not set
```

Trying to launch other processes will yield other error messages, fail silently, or, in some cases like `ls`, work as expected. This makes it a bit hard for me to actually see a pattern yet.

Can you point out what is causing the second approach to behave differently than the first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message `DISPLAY is not set` tells you that `xterm` didn't find the `DISPLAY` *environment variable*. All graphical-output programs use this environment variable to connect to your screen.

It didn't find the variable because the environment was empty (it's the last `NULL` in your `posix_spawnp` function call). It seems that `popen` reuses the environment of current process, so it doesn't have this problem.

You might want to pass a manually-created environment, containing only the needed stuff, or just pass whatever environment your process has. The latter is more flexible (`xterm` will inherit various configuration settings from your process, which inherits them from your shell) but may be a security risk.

To access the environment of your process, use the [`environ`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) global variable or change your `main` function to receive an additional parameter:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    ...
    posix_spawnp(&pid, p.we_wordv[0], NULL, NULL, p.we_wordv, envp);
}
```

Comment: Quickly gave that a try (to pass on `environ`) and that seems to do the trick, nice! One follow-up question though: where would one usually declare `environ` - at the top of the program, or just where you need it, for example in a function body?